# Flutter TabBar not keeping state when swithing tabs even after using AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin and super.build(context)

Tags: flutter, dart

My app has two tabs and switching the tabs doesn't keep its state. I searched the web and found to use `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` with `wantKeepAlive` as `true` and `super.build(context)`. I did exactly what was told by other users across the web and stackoverflow but the problem still exists.
Here is my code:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin{
@override
bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
super.build(context);
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter GridView',
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  theme: ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Colors.blue,
    accentColor: Colors.white,
  ),
  home: DefaultTabController(
    length: 2,
          child: Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        title: Text('AIO'),
        bottom: TabBar(
          tabs: <Widget>[
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.favorite)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        children: <Widget>[
          gridView,
          SecondPage(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}}
```

Comment: You were on the right track, the AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin should go on the Widgets that are the bodies of each of your tabs. Instead of the Widget that has the TabBar.

Answer (score 1):

Use PageStorage, PageStorageBucket and PageStorageKey.

Create an instance field of PageStorageBucket, wrap your TabBarView with PageStorage, then add PageStorageKey to your GridView.

```dart
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();
  //...

  body: PageStorage(
    bucket: bucket,
    child: TabBarView(
      children: <Widget>[
        gridView, // add to GridView(key: PageStorageKey('MyGridViewKey'), //...
        SecondPage(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  //...
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was slightly different than OPs but I want to post it here in case anyone else is running into the same issue. If you're not using a `TabBarView` (in my case I can't use `TabBarView` because it doesn't seem to work with dynamically sized pages) and a `Center` to hold your tab pages like this:

```
        Center(
          child: [
            Page1(),
            Page2(),
          ][_tabIndex],
        )
```

then the AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin that I added to `Page1State` and `Page2State` was not working for me. I had to use an `IndexedStack` in order for it to work:

```
        IndexedStack(
          index: _tabIndex,
          children: [
            Page1(),
            Page2()
          ],
        )
```

So it looks like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        child: TabBar(controller: _tabController, tabs: [
          Tab(text: "Tab 1"),
          Tab(text: "Tab 2"),
        ]),
      ),
      IndexedStack(
        index: _tabIndex,
        children: [
          Page1(),
          Page2()
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```